# Filling the inverse of the CGPath without clipping

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, quartz-2d, clipping, cgpath

Say I have a CGPath which is a circle in the CGContextRef. What I would like to do is to fill the inverse of the path with color. Demonstrated below where the circle is the current path drawn and I would like to fill the inverse of the circle with color, leaving a hollow hole:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First add the rectangle to the path and then add the circle (or whatever your path is) to the same path. Then do an even-odd fill which will won't fill the circle because that is covered by both the circle and the rectangle.

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, bigRect);      // add the big rect
CGPathAddPath(path, NULL, circlePath);   // add your shape (the circle)
CGContextDrawPath(path, kCGPathEOFill);  // even-odd fill
```

Comment: that is a good suggesting except I have overlapping circles and even odd produces undesirable results

Answer (score 0):

Since you have overlapping circles you'll need to create a single path which represents the union of those circles, then add that path to your rectangle and fill as David suggested.

To create the union of the circle paths, this project will prove invaluable:

https://bitbucket.org/martinwinter/vectorbooleancg

Make sure that you check out the 'CGPath' branch to get iOS support.